# Render view with all css classes inline for html email

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

As terrible and disgusting as this sounds, I would like to be able to render a view in ASP.NET MVC so that all css classes in the elements are rendered inline in the tags. The sole purpose of this is to have email clients recognise html, as I believe that style must be inline for it to be recognised in email messages.

Is there any facility in ASP.NET MVC (or ASP.NET) that allows this?

Comment: So ASP.NET would look at the `class` or `id` attribute of each html element, lookup the class/id in the associated `.css` file and then add a `style` attribute to the element with the content found in the `.css` file?

Comment: i don't believe there is any facility in ASP.NET for this. I see two options: 1) Physically c+p the .css content into a inline stylesheet, or 2) Create a Html Helper that renders HTML (the actual `<style type='text/css'>` and the classes) directly to the html. You could put the smarts to grab only the CSS you want, but that's another complication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen this?

http://premailer.dialect.ca/

Source code is available for it as well.